# How to change DrawerArrow color when using Theme.AppCompat

Tags: android, material-design, materialized-views

I am using `Toolbar+NavigationDrawer` with the **Theme.AppCompat**.

here is my `style.xml:`

```
<style name="BlueTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/BlueTheme.DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="BlueTheme.DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

but the `drawer arrow still has a alpha and is not solid white.`

Like this:

**[ScreenShot](http://www.dss886.com/images/post_images/temp/device-2014-12-03-151459.png)**

(sorry i haven't have enough reputation to post images)

It seems that the `drawerArrowStyle` attribute doesn't work, I wonder if I made some mistakes. What can I do to `change the DrawerToggler to solid white?`

(ps: When I use `origin ActionBar It works right,` something turns wrong when I replace ActionBar to Toolbar)

(Forgive my poor English... )

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I just faced the same problem.
Are you setting the custom toolbar theme in layout xml ?
You have to use `app:theme` instead of `android:theme`

Even though the `drawerArrowStyle` is set in App Theme, not ActionBar theme, it didn't work while I had the `android:theme` property set for the toolbar.
Once I changed it to `app:theme` it all started to work as documented.

Comment: This was the key.  android:theme seemed to work for L, but for JellyBean I had to switch to app:theme